# Unable to get the payload from GitHub web hook trigger in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, github-webhook, jenkins-github-plugin

I have configured a Github web hook with the below settings:
Payload URL: https:///github-webhook/
Content Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Events : Pushes, Pull Requests

The Jenkins job that I have, is a pipeline job that has the below enabled:
Build Trigger: GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling

With the above configuration, I see that in response to an event ie; push/PR in GitHub, the jenkins job gets triggered successfully. In GitHub, under Recent Deliveries for the web hook, I see the details of the payload and a successful Response of 200.

I am trying to get the payload in Jenkins Pipeline for further processing. I need some details eg: PR URL/PR number, refs type, branch name etc for conditional processing in the Jenkins Pipeline.

I tried accessing the "payload" variable (as mentioned in other stack overflow posts and the documentations available around) and printing it as part of the pipeline, but I have had no luck yet.

So my question is, How can I get the payload from GitHub web hook trigger in my Jenkins Pipeline ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to select `Content type: application/json` in your webhook in GitHub. Then you would be able to access any variable from the payload GitHub sends as follows: `$. pull_request.url` for pr url, for example.

Comment: @bad_coder - thanks for the edit. I am new to this platform, still learning the nitty-gritties.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this is possible.

With the GitHub plugin we use (Pipeline Github), PR number is stored in the variable `CHANGE_ID`.
PR URL is pretty easy to generate given the PR number. Branch name is stored in the variable `BRANCH_NAME`. In case of pull requests, the global variable `pullRequest` is populated [with lots of data](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin#pullrequest).

Missing information can be obtained from Github by using their API. Here's an example of checking if PR is "behind", you can modify that to your specific requirements:

```
def checkPrIsNotBehind(String repo) {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "<...>", 
            passwordVariable: 'TOKEN', 
            usernameVariable: 'USER')]) {
        def headers = ' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" '
        def url = "https://api.github.com/repos/<...>/<...>/pulls/${env.CHANGE_ID}"
        def head_sha = sh (label: "Check PR head SHA", 
                              returnStdout: true,
                              script: "curl -s ${url} ${headers} | jq -r .head.sha").trim().toUpperCase()
        println "PR head sha is ${head_sha}"
        
        headers = ' -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" '
        url = "https://api.github.com/repos/<...>/${repo}/compare/${pullRequest.base}...${head_sha}"
        def behind_by = sh (label: "Check PR commits behind", 
                              returnStdout: true,
                              script: "curl -s ${url} ${headers} | jq -r .behind_by").trim().toUpperCase()
        
        if (behind_by != '0') {
            currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"
            currentBuild.displayName = "#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-Out of date"
            error("The head ref is out of date. Please update your branch.")
        }
    }
}
```